# c: skip an element with scanf

Tags: scanf, element, skip

I'm trying to scan a file that contains 13 ints which are to be stored in 13 variables. Is there a way to loop over this, while skipping the i-th element? I'm anticipating there might be a solution, which have yet eluded me, perhaps similar to the code below:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
  fscanf(file, %d, &variables[i]); // somehow apply i to %d
```

instead of the obvious but lengthy and unclean:

```
fscanf(file, %d, &variable1);
fscanf(file, %*d, %d, &variable2);
fscanf(file, %*d %*d, %d, &variable3); // etc
```

thanks

Comment: You want to read an element, skip 1 element, read an element, skip 2 elements, read an element, skip 3 elements, and so on?

Comment: yes, storing element x in variable x :)

Comment: That's not the same thing. You want to store element 0 in variable[0], element 2 in variable[1], element 5 in variable[2], and so on?

Comment: If you just want to store element x in variable[x], what's wrong with the first loop? Is it that you want to use different variables, not an array?

Comment: I have a struct with an int member 'value', and I want the scanned ints to replace those values. Above example was just a way to avoid writing a lot of variable names by using an index. But I realize that it's probably a confusing question, as nobody has tried to answer it, so I'm going to try and solve it another way

Comment: in the first loop, won't it just keep scanning the first element into i-th variable?

Comment: No, after you scan an input, the next call starts from where the last one left off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int *variables[] = { &variable1, &variable2, &variable3, ... };

for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
  fscanf(file, "%d", variables[i]);
}
```